# Issue with Python displaying all available color pairs with Curses

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I am running Python 3.10 and I am having an issue with curses, specifically when trying to utilize the full range of color pairs

`curses.COLORS` returns `256`

`curses.COLOR_PAIRS` returns `65536`

`curses.has_extended_color_support()` returns `True`

But when I initialize a color pair of 256, 512, 768, 1024, etc... the color pair seems to reset the colors that were initialized

Additionally, if I am trying to display any color pair > 255 (`curses.COLORS - 1`) it uses one of the pairs < 255 instead of the color pair ID I set. Curses allows me to run init_pair with these numbers, but it ignores them completely, and instead uses the color pair < 255

Here is an example code snippet

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

"""
Python3.10 added extended color support to curses
curses.COLOR_PAIRS (xterm-256color) returns 65,536
curses.COLORS (xterm-256color) returns 256
"""

import curses


def cycler(start_color, end_color):
    # cycle through all possible color IDs or pair IDs curses can display, loops indefinitely
    while True:
        for i in range(start_color, end_color):
            yield i


def main(stdscr):
    curses.start_color()
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()

    RED = 1  # Reserve the red color at color ID 1
    curses.init_color(RED, 1000, 0, 0)

    color_cycler = cycler(2, curses.COLORS - 1)  # RED is reserved at 1, start at 2
    pair_cycler = cycler(1, curses.COLOR_PAIRS - 1)

    has_extended_support = curses.has_extended_color_support()
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, f"COLORS:{curses.COLORS} "
                        f"COLOR_PAIRS:{curses.COLOR_PAIRS} "
                        f"ExtendedSupport:{has_extended_support}", curses.color_pair(1))

    for y in range(1, height - 1):
        for x in range(0, width, 5):

            color_id = next(color_cycler)
            pair_id = next(pair_cycler)

            intensity = int((color_id / (curses.COLORS - 1)) * 1000)
            curses.init_color(color_id, intensity, intensity, intensity)

            # create a new color pair, (RED) foreground, (color) background
            curses.init_pair(pair_id, RED, color_id)
            string = str(pair_id).rjust(5, ' ')
            stdscr.addstr(y, x, string, curses.color_pair(pair_id))

    stdscr.noutrefresh()
    curses.doupdate()
    stdscr.getch()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

And here is a screenshot of what it generates for me (notice the numbers 256, 512, 768, 1024)
the numbers represent the color pair ID

[image]

Terminal apps I've tried:

- gnome-terminal
- terminology
- tilda

All with the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use the *extended* interface, as noted in the release announcement for [ncurses 6.1](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.1.html):

> The motivation for making this extension came from noticing that termcap applications could (though not realistically) use larger numbers than would fit in 16-bits, and the fact that the number of color pairs for a 256-color xterm could not be expressed in terminfo (i.e., 32767 versus 65536). Also, a few terminals support direct-colors, which could use the extension.

Python probably doesn't do that (its binding only covers part of ncurses), so color-values and color-pairs are a signed 16-bit number:

```
0..32767
```

Now... python 3.10 was released in [October 2021](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html).  The most recent ncurses fix related to color-pairs was in [August 2021](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#index-t20210821).  If you're using an older version of ncurses (e.g., by compiling python on something [very old](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/8-stream/baseos/aarch64/Packages/ncurses-devel-6.1-9.20180224.el8.aarch64.html), such as RHEL8), then it's just a known bug to which the answer would be "upgrade".

Comment: I already have python 3.10.12 and libncursesw6 version (6.3-2ubuntu0.1), but I can't still use the init_extended_color and the init_extended_pair. Why?

Comment: as noted: *Python probably doesn't do that*

Comment: Thanks @Tomas Dickey. I would like the above python code converted to C or C++. Can someone do the conversion because I'm not very familiar with python. At least in C or C++ I can use the init_extended_color and the init_extended_pair functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The python developers currently have about [six thousand](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues) open bugs, but only seventy for the curses binding.  None of those deal with this topic; you might want to open an issue for it.

Comment: Where I can find a C or C++ example which deal with true color using curses? The above code use python macros which encapsulate curses calls and I can't create a C or C++ code that behave like the python code above.

Answer (score 0):

I created this C++ version of the above sample, using `init_extended_color` and `init_extended_pair`. I don't know if it's correct.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class Cycler
{
private:
    int startColor;
    int endColor;
    int current;

public:
    Cycler(int start, int end) : startColor(start), endColor(end), current(start) {}

    int next()
    {
        if (current >= endColor)
        {
            current = startColor;
        }
        return current++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    initscr();       // Initialize the window
    start_color();   // Start color functionality
    noecho();        // Do not echo any keypresses
    curs_set(FALSE); // Do not display a cursor

    int height, width;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, height, width);

    int RED = 1;                          // Reserve the red color at color ID 1
    init_extended_color(RED, 1000, 0, 0); // Initialize the red color

    Cycler colorCycler(2, COLORS - 1); // RED is reserved at 1, start at 2
    Cycler pairCycler(1, COLOR_PAIRS - 1);

    bool has_extended_support = has_colors() && can_change_color();
    attr_on(COLOR_PAIR(1), NULL);
    mvprintw(0, 0, "COLORS:%d COLOR_PAIRS:%d ExtendedSupport:%s", COLORS, COLOR_PAIRS, has_extended_support ? "True" : "False");
    attr_off(COLOR_PAIR(1), NULL);

    for (int y = 1; y < height - 1; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 5)
        {
            int color_id = colorCycler.next();
            int pair_id = pairCycler.next();

            int intensity = int((color_id / double(COLORS - 1)) * 1000);
            init_extended_color(color_id, intensity, intensity, intensity);

            // Create a new color pair, (RED) foreground, (color) background
            init_extended_pair(pair_id, RED, color_id);

            char str[6];
            attr_on(COLOR_PAIR(pair_id), NULL);
            mvprintw(y, x, "%5d", pair_id);
            attr_off(COLOR_PAIR(pair_id), NULL);
        }
    }

    refresh(); // Refresh the screen
    getch();   // Wait for a keypress
    endwin();  // End the window session

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Here the output]